# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'collapsed' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change a value property in a recursive method.

I'm using create-react-library and launch my library and dont show me an error but when I add my library to a project show me next error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'collapsed' of object '#<Object>'
(anonymous function)
  100 | export const unCheckBranch = (branch: IHierarchyBranch) => {
  101 |     if (branch.children.length > 0) {
  102 |         branch.children.forEach((child: IHierarchyBranch) => {
> 103 |             child.collapsed = false;
  104 |         });
  105 |     }
  106 |
```

How can solve it?

Why when launch as a project dont crash and when add to a project crash??

Comment: It looks like your each child object is immutable

Comment: mmmm how can make mutable ?

Comment: I think instead of trying to make it mutable, you're supposed to be return the new object